# Derivative of functional given by integral

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm studying the nonlinear eigenvalue problem for the Laplacian and I'm trying to calculate the derivative of the functional
$$
F(u) = {1 \over q} \int_\Omega |u|^q dx - 1
$$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded domain, $u = u(x) \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $q \in (1, 2^*)$, with $2^* = {2N \over N-2}$. My first thought was to try calculating directly like
$$
{1 \over q}\lim_{t \to 0} \left[ {\int_\Omega |u+tv|^q - |u|^q dx \over t} \right]
$$
Obviously is not going great. I can't seem to find a way to simplify the integrand so I can easily evaluate the limit as in the case $q = 2$. I thought about splitting in the cases $1 < q < 2$ and $2 < q < 2^*$ but I don't think it leads anywhere. I think I'm missing something really obvious to be honest... Any ideas?

Comment: What is relationship between u and x?

Comment: @herbsteinberg sorry, u = u(x)

Comment: How does u define F(u) after integration?

Comment: Differentiate $x \mapsto x^q$, apply the dominated convergence theorem to pass into the limit where it is legal to use the above differentiation, throw away the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where it is easier to work formally at first. Consider a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is $C^1$ and the functional on $H_0^1(\Omega)$ defined by
$$
F(u) = \int_\Omega \phi(u(x))dx.
$$
The function derivative of this is given by (this is equivalent to your definition) $$
\delta F(u)v = \left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon = 0} F(u + \epsilon v) = \int_\Omega \left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon} \phi(u+\epsilon v)\right|_{\epsilon = 0}dx.
$$
Here I am being a bit loose with the interchange of limiting processes, but when computing functional derivatives, one can compute the derivative assuming more regularity than is necessarily present in the problem and end up deriving something that works in the more general case. This can be rigorously justified via DCT or something similar, but formal manipulation of functional derivatives is done very often, especially when one doesn't know *a priori* which space different components will belong in in nonlinear problems.

One can use a Taylor series of $\phi$ in terms of $\epsilon$ to get $$\phi(u+\epsilon v) = \phi(u) + \epsilon\phi'(u)v + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2),$$ which is sufficient to show that
$$
\delta F(u)v = \int_\Omega\phi'(u)v~dx
$$
using the limit definition of the derivative as in your original formulation.
For your functional, we have $\phi(z) = \frac{1}{q}|z|^q$, which is $C^1$ for $q>1$ and its derivative is given by $$\phi'(z) = \frac{1}{q}(q|z|^{q-1})\left(\frac{z}{|z|}\right) = z|z|^{q-2}.$$ Here I have used that $z/|z| = \mathrm{sign}(z)$. For $q>1$, this function is still continuous at $0$, so we are good. The derivative of the your functional is then given by
$$\delta F(u)v = \int_\Omega u|u|^{q-2}v~dx.$$